# declaring a hash table in one file and using it in another in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I need to create a hash table in one file and use in in another. The reason for it is that that the table is my "database" and will be changed, and I want it to seat with all the other data files, and not with the script files.

How can I use the table in my script?

Comment: So your hash table is inside another Perl script?

Comment: @Zaid, yes, kind of. It's not a script, but a file dedicated solely to the declaration of the hash table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your hashtable in a global or package variable. Then use the `do` command to load the definition into another script:

```
 datafiles/database.def
 ---------------------------
 package ProjectData;
 our %DATA = ('abc' => 'def', 'ghi' => 'jkl', ...);


 scripts/myscript.pl
 ------------------------
 use strict;
 do 'datafiles/database.def';
 ... do something with %ProjectData::DATA ...
```

Comment: I'd have thought of `use` or `require`, but I guess `do` works if you want specific file path.

Comment: `require` is also a good choice, depending on your error checking needs. On error (e.g., an incorrect filename), `require` will "raise an exception" while `do` will just return `undef` and proceed. If you use `require`, you also have to remember to make your file return a "true" value.

Comment: `do` is not appropriate there. `do` is for when you don't use `package`. `require` (usually via `use`) is for when you use `package` (which should be all the time).

Comment: Note that loading at run-time like this is not only odd, it can cause "used only once" warnings.

Comment: I see you reinserted the bug in your node. **Never use `do` with a file with a package.**

Answer (score 1):

There are too many ways to do it!

A simple one is to write your data to a file as [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and load it using Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS.

**update**:

You can also use the `do` builtin to read and execute a perl file from another script. I.e.:

```
do "config.pl";
```

Or use a configuration file format that allows for complex data structures (XML, JSON, yaml, .ini, etc.).

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to make a text file and them parsing it, that's what I do right now, it just becomes to complicated as the data grows, and I don't have all the data right now, I want to be able to add keys and values without changing the script code (it's a hash of hashes).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for a [tied hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/AnyDBM_File.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not be the best solution, but you could just use [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) or [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), both of which are in the core since forever (5.7.3 and 5.5, respectively).

Alternatively, you could put them in another module and use/require that, ala

```
package MyImportantHash;
```

`use Exporter;`

```
our @EXPORT = qw( %important_hash );

our %important_hash = (
              some_key  => 'some_value',
         );

1;
```

And in your main package,

```
use MyImportantHash;
say "$_ => $important_hash{$_}" for sort keys %important_hash;
```

Of course, this all assumes that you don't want changes in the hash while in-memory to automatically show up in the file. If you do, look no further than davorg's answer.