# Accessing perl hash using package

Tags: perl, hash, package

Kindly answer to the question posted in the below link:

[How do I populate a hash (that has been defined in a separate file) in my Perl script and do necessary operations on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631292/how-do-i-populate-a-hash-that-has-been-defined-in-a-separate-file-in-my-perl-s)

Please look into the last part of the page.. i.e

Now suppose say I want to access a hash from file2.def or file3.def and so on..

How can I make my script generic such that it automatically captures the hash name from the included file and automatically accesses its key->value pairs

i.e

```
$file1::"here I want it to take the name of the hash depending on the file included"
```

Comment: @Borodin -  I need an answer for the last part. Please help

Comment: As well as the `do 'filename'` you could read the top few lines of the file and extract the hash name.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - Could you please elaborate it a bit?

Comment: There are lots of places that describe how to read a file and find some text in it, so getting the name of the hash should be easy. The problem is using that name in the code. That requires _using a string as a variable name_ which is possible in Perl. Do a web search to find out how. But that search will also show many discussions of why _using a string as a variable name_ is a **BAD** thing.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - Hmm thats right. Thanks a lot for the reply. I will do check it out.